# Chrome extension content script - .click() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying for hours and I can't get this working. I've written a content script that executes when the user loads a page. The click() method just simply won't work when I try click an element. I've tried multiple ways and it always works from the console, but not when I load the page.

The element I want to click:

```
<a id="startButton" href="javascript: popupHand.showPopup('popupLoginV2','loginHand.init()','','',true);" class="buttonGreen1 buttonSize1">Megpörgetem</a>
```

manifest.json - content script part

```
{
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.bonuszbrigad.hu/bonuszkerek"],
      "js": ["plugin/jquery-3.2.0.min.js", "js/page_wheel.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
}
```

page_wheel.js

```
function spinWheel() {
    var spinButton = $("#startButton");

    if (spinButton.text() === "Már pörgettél") {
        return "wait";
    }

    else if (spinButton.text() === "Megpörgetem") {
        console.log("spin is available");

        spinButton.on("click",
            function () {
                console.log("inside click action");

                var popupLogin = $("#popup_login");
                console.log(popupLogin);

                if (popupLogin === null) {
                    return "login"
                } else {
                    return "success";
                }
            }
        );

        spinButton.trigger("click");
    }
}
```

When I load the page, the console logs show that it managed to enter

- *spinButton.on("click", function (){...});*

But there weren't any actual clicks made on the website. When I test the click method in the console, both of the below solutions work:

- *$("#startButton").click()*
- *document.getElementById("startButton").click();*

Also I see the same console logs - when executing click method from the console - but this way it's actually working.

Does anyone have an idea what is the problem? :/

Comment: also, I just tested if there are any conflicting extensions. disabled everything besides this current one. still no success

Comment: I may have found what is the problem - the execution environment of content scripts. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment

Comment: I do not see an invocation of .click() in your content script.

Comment: The element may be added dynamically by the page code after the page has been loaded. In that case use setInterval checks or MutationObserver.

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem. In my case, I realized that there were HTML DOM and script load synchronizes. So when you call the click event, it was still fulfill loaded. So I added the script that invokes the click event into the `window.load` and it worked.

My script looks like below:

```
window.onload = function () {
  const btn = document.getElementById('J_LinkBuy')

  if (btn !== null) {
    btn.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: You can use onclick attribute on any HTML tag and use it to call JavaScript functions.

```
<a onclick="sayHi('Hi')"> Click me </a>
<script>function sayHi(message){alert(message)}</script>
```

Solution 2: Use jquery click event function.

> Remember, the jquery click should be called only after the target html
> element is generated. the click call won't work or else

```
$(css_selector).click();
```